# Android Firebase OrderBy

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a hard time with figuring out how to query my Firebase database. Here is what it looks like.

[image: Firebase Database]

And here is my code:

```
//RETRIEVE
    public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve()
    {

        String myUserId = acct.getId();

        //db.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        db.child("/users/uid").equals(myUserId)
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                //fetchData(dataSnapshot);
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return spacecrafts;
    }
```

So `db.addChildEventListener` will retrieve the entire database. But what I want is to only retrieve data for users whose uid is equal to String myUserId. And I want to sort in ascending order by Level. I have read the docs and watched videos but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using OrderBy child  and then filtering it out on query like mentioned in Docs 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response. Yes, I have looked at that documentation. The problem with the documentation is that they don't show how the dinosaur database is structured. If I posted a question about problems I am having with my database and didn't show the structure, someone would ask for me to show the structure. I don't know how to get a reference to users with a specific uid and order by what appears to be a sibling , Level. I have a SQL background and don't understand NoSQL.

Answer (score 3):

```
Query query = db.child("users").orderByChild("uid").equalTo("myUserId");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println("User "+userSnapshot.child("uid").getValue());
        }
    }
    ...
```

But if you're frequently accessing the data by UID, you're off restructuring your database to store all users under their own UID:

```
users
  myUserId
    Level: 2
    NumCorrect: 8
```

You can then read the data with:

```
db.child("users/myUserId").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        fetchData(dataSnapshot);
    }
```

For more on Firebase queries, see the [Firebase documentation on sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data). Since you're new to NoSQL, I also recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Comment: Thanks Frank. I can see from your query how that would select a certain uid. But would it ensure that the results would be sorted in ascending order by Level?

Comment: A Firebase query can only order/filter on one property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Ok, maybe I can load the snapshot results into a list and then sort the list. Then send the list to the Custom Adapter for the ListView. So new to Android. I am a C# SQL Server developer by day. This would be so much easier if Android used C# instead of Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the array list

```
    ArrayList<UserModel> user_list = new ArrayList<>();       

 for (DataSnapshot snapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                UserModel userModel = snapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);

                user_list.add(userModel);
                Collections.reverse(user_list);

            }
```